# How to see memory allocated to Oracle JVM

Tags: oracle

I am trying to execute some java code in Oracle JVM but getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.

so I want to dedicate more memory to Oracle JVM. How shuld we do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Seems you are exceeding the heap size of the OJVM.

First you need to find out how much heap size you have available right now in total:
Take a look at your initialization parameter `JAVA_POOL_SIZE`. If it is 0, then you are using automatic memory management (10g or 11g) and the heap size is determined by the Oracle server "automagically". Then you can take `sga_target` (10g) or `memory_target` (11g) as an upper limit.

The maximum heap size per session is limited by the parameter `java_max_sessionspace_size` (value 0 means default of 4GB).

With these two values at hand, take the smaller one and check if the memory requirements/heap size caused by your code *should* fit into this amount of memory.

- If yes: you have a memory leak in your java code.
- If not: increase
  either `java_pool_size`, `sga_target`/`memory_target` or
  `java_max_sessionspace_size`.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chnine.htm#BABGFDAE (Java Memory Usage) and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams099.htm#REFRN10074 + http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams100.htm#REFRN10075 (Parameters) for detailled documentation.

And regarding your question "How to see memory allocated to Oracle JVM" in the subject:

```
select * from v$sgastat where pool = 'java pool';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html, specifically -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio and -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio

Comment: I am invoking the java code through the stored procedure so there is any way set these parameters..??

Answer (score 0):

The above suggestions didn't work for me.  You can use

```
select getMaxMemorySize() from dual
```

To show this.  You can then set it using:

```
create or replace function setMaxMemorySize(num number) return number
is language java name
'oracle.aurora.vm.OracleRuntime.setMaxMemorySize(long) returns long';
```

then calling this function:

```
select setMaxMemorySize(1024*1024*1024) from dual;
```

Note: This only sets the max memory for the session.  You will need to call this for each new session.